# Iterator of Iterator

Tags: java, iterator

I am trying to create an iterator of iterator, supporting any type in Java. The purpose is to iterate over the objects of the iterators.

But I have a type mismatch and I don't see how to initialize my implementation.

The first idea that I had in mind is to make my class implement `Iterator<Iterator<T>>` but this would not work because the next method will have the signature `public Iterator<T> next()` which does not correspond to what I want to do. Instead of returning of `Iterator<T>`, I want to return the type `T`.

So I create another interface which is very similar to the Iterator interface :

```
  public interface MyIterator<T extends Iterator<T>> {

    public boolean hasNext();

    public T next();
}
```

My iterator takes a type T which is an iterator. Here is my implementation (without remove) :

```
public class IteratorOfIterator<T extends Iterator<T>> implements MyIterator<T> {

private T[] iterators;

private T currentIterator;

private int currentIndex;

public IteratorOfIterator(T[] iterators){
    this.iterators = iterators;
    this.currentIndex = 0;
    this.currentIterator = iterators[currentIndex];
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return currentIndex < iterators.length - 1 || currentIterator.hasNext();
}

public T next() {
    if(!this.currentIterator.hasNext()){
        currentIndex++;
        this.currentIterator = iterators[currentIndex];
    }
    return currentIterator.next();
}
```

If I want to test my iterator but I have a type mismatch, how can I initialize it? Here is an example of I want to do:

```
String[] strings = {"peanut","butter","coco","foo","bar"};

Object[] iterators = {strings};

MyIterator<String> myIterator = new IteratorOfIterator<String>(iterators); // <-- in this line
```

The error says : `Bound mismatch: The type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Iterator<T>> of the type IteratorOfIterator<T> IteratorOfIterator.java`

How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot for your advice.

PS: I totally understand the problem. I understand that, for instance, the type String does not implement MyIterator interface so this is why it's not a good substitute. My problem is I don't how can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work,

```
public interface MyIterator<T extends Iterator<T>>
```

This means `T` must be an `Iterator` itself.

You don't want T do be restricted to a specific type,

```
public interface MyIterator<T>
```

BUT you want your Iterators to be of type `Iterator<T>`

```
public class IteratorOfIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

private Iterator<T>[] iterators;

private Iterator<T> currentIterator;

private int currentIndex;

public IteratorOfIterator(Iterator<T>[] iterators){
    this.iterators = iterators;
    this.currentIndex = 0;
    this.currentIterator = iterators[currentIndex];
}
```

so you can use `Iterator` instead of `MyIterator` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Iterator<String> myIterator = Arrays.asList(strings).iterator();
```

There is no standard way to directly obtain an iterator from a Java array, so you can either first convert it to a `List`, or build your own iterator for the array.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating iterator of iterators and the constructors defines the array of iterators, So the calling code should be like:

```
    List list1 = new ArrayList();
    List list2 = new ArrayList();
    Iterator<String> iterator1 = list1.iterator();
    Iterator<String> iterator2 = list2.iterator();      
    Iterator[] iteratorList = {iterator1, iterator2};    
    MyIterator<String> myIterator = new IteratorOfIterator(iteratorList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of IteratorOfIterator is to hide implementation details of dealing with multiple iterators, so that client iterates through elements as a single iterator.  In a sense, IterorOfIterator acts as an adapter to other iterators.  [See this page for the concept - RoundRobinIterator](http://www.codescream.com/ContentDisplay?targetContent=RoundRobinIterator)

Code here utilizes a queue to maintain sequence of iterators. 'currentIter' variable is set by polling from the queue. setNext is a state machine, which transits among iterators and set next value to iterate.

```
public class IteratorOfIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
private final Queue<Iterator<T>> iterQueue;
private Iterator<T> currentIter;
private T nextValue;

public IteratorOfIterator(List<Iterator<T>> iters) {
    this.iterQueue = new LinkedList<Iterator<T>>(iters);
    this.currentIter = null;
    this.nextValue = null;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.nextValue != null || setNext();
}

@Override
public T next() {
    if (this.nextValue != null) {
        T next = this.nextValue;
        this.nextValue = null;
        setNext();
        return next;
    }
    return null;
}

private boolean setNext() {
    while (true) {
        if (currentIter == null && iterQueue.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (currentIter == null && !iterQueue.isEmpty()) {
            currentIter = iterQueue.poll();
        }
        if (currentIter != null && currentIter.hasNext()) {
            this.nextValue = currentIter.next();
            return true;
        }
        if (currentIter != null && !currentIter.hasNext()) {
            if (!iterQueue.isEmpty()) {
                currentIter = iterQueue.poll();
            } else {
                currentIter = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```